# the use of getitimer and setitimer in C

Tags: c, time, setitimer

I am writing the following C code to get the time taken to perform a simple operation using getitimer and setitimer.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INTERVAL 1        /* number of milliseconds to go off */

int main() {
    double sum = 0;
    struct itimerval initial, updated;

    initial.it_value.tv_sec     = INTERVAL;
    initial.it_value.tv_usec    = 999999;
    initial.it_interval = initial.it_value;
    memcpy(&(initial.it_interval), &(initial.it_value), sizeof( initial.it_value )); 
    printf("%ld\n", initial.it_value.tv_usec);

    if (setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &initial, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("error calling setitimer()");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (unsigned int i; i < 100; i++) 
        sum += 1./i;

    if (getitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &updated) == -1) {
        perror("error calling getitimer()");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Time started = %ld\n; Time ended = %ld\n: Time taken = %ld\n",
           initial.it_value.tv_usec, updated.it_value.tv_usec,
           initial.it_value.tv_usec - updated.it_value.tv_usec);
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled with:

```
$ gcc -o timer -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic getitimer.c -lrt -03
```

However, my answer is always 999999 (I have raised and decreased the 100):

```
 ./timer 
999999
Time started = 999999
; Time endd = 0
: Time taken = 999999
```

What is my error?  Also, I wanted to ask what is the highest precision I can get using a progrma like this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The edited code is not an improvement.  The value INT_MAX is outside the range of permitted values for the `tv_usec` component (valid range is 0..999999 microseconds), hence the error.

Comment: thanks! However, no matter how big or small my loop, I am getting 0 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

the main thing I see is the division operations are using integer division.  So:

```
initial.it_value.tv_sec     = INTERVAL/1000000;
```

places 0 in tv.sec

```
initial.it_value.tv_usec    = (INTERVAL/1000000) * 1000000;
```

places 0 in tv_usec

```
initial.it_interval = initial.it_value;
```

in general, when assigning a multi field struct, use `memcpy()` rather than a direct assignment. (direct assignment will work for initialization but not for assignment.)

So, the posted code sets the 'interval' to 0

so of course, the resulting values are 0

this is a key statement from the man page for setitimer() and getitimer()

"Timers decrement from it_value to zero, generate a signal, and reset to
       it_interval.  A timer which is set to zero (it_value  is  zero  or the timer expires and it_interval is zero) stops."

Suggest: *following edited*

```
initial.it_value.tv_set = INTERVAL;
initial.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

memcpy( &(initial.it_interval), &(initial.it_value), sizeof( initial.it_value ) );

...
```

Comment: What's your reasoning behind 'use `memcpy()` rather than assignment'?  It seems highly dubious to me.

Comment: This does not work: in fact  does not even compile. I guess I did not get the suggestion!

Comment: @user3236841, I do see where I made a keypunch error of typing `tvuser` when I should have typed `tv_usec`.  However, that keypunch error should have been obvious to you.   BTW: I just compiled/ran your posted code, with my suggested modifications, It cleanly compiled.  It ran and produced the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I made the corrections earlier and the code did not compile. Here is what I got: getitimer.c: In function ‘main’:
getitimer.c:16:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘memcpy’
  memcpy( initial.it_interval, initial.it_value, sizeof( initial.it_value ));     aand so on..........could you please post your complete code?
          ^
In file included from getitimer.c:5:0:
/usr/include/string.h:42:14: note: expected ‘void * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘struct timeval’
 extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
              ^

Comment: Tthe first two parameters to the `memcpy() function must be the addresses not the contents.  Suggest using: `memcpy( &(initial.it_interval), &(initial.it_value), sizeof( initial.it_value ) );`

Comment: thanks! the program compiles but the problem does not go away. I will submit an edited program and you can try it and see. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the main problem with the latest code is that the call to `getitimer()` is referencing a different timer than the call to `setitime()`

However, the following code makes it simple to use

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <limits.h>
//#include <string.h>

// do not place comments on same line as #define statement
// always surround numeric values with parens to avoid 'text replacement' errors
// wrong comment:  number of milliseconds to go off

// number of seconds in interval
#define INTERVAL (1)

// number of usec in interval
#define MICRO_INTERVAL (999999)

int main() {
    //double sum = 0;
    struct itimerval initial;
    struct itimerval updated;

    initial.it_value.tv_sec     = INTERVAL;
    initial.it_value.tv_usec    = MICRO_INTERVAL;
    initial.it_interval.tv_sec  = INTERVAL;
    initial.it_interval.tv_usec = MICRO_INTERVAL;

    // remove this line: initial.it_interval = initial.it_value;
    // remove this line: memcpy(&(initial.it_interval), &(initial.it_value), sizeof( initial.it_value ));
    //printf("%ld\n", initial.it_value.tv_usec);

    printf( "Time value: %ld.%ld\n", initial.it_value.tv_sec, initial.it_value.tv_usec );
    printf( "Time interval: %ld.%ld\n", initial.it_interval.tv_sec, initial.it_interval.tv_usec );

    if (setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &initial, &updated) == -1)
    {
        perror("error calling setitimer()");
        exit(1);
    }

    //for (unsigned int i=0; i < 10; i++)  // must initialize the 'i' variable
    //    sum += 1./i;

    // the 'which' parameter should be 'ITIMER_VIRTUAL'
    //     as that is what was started in the call to setitimer()
    //if (getitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &updated) == -1)
    //{
    //    perror("error calling getitimer()");
    //    exit(1);
    //}

    if (setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &initial, &updated) == -1)
    {
        perror("error calling setitimer()");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf( "end interval counter: %ld.%ld\n", updated.it_interval.tv_sec, updated.it_interval.tv_usec );
    printf( "end value counter: %ld.%ld\n", updated.it_value.tv_sec, updated.it_value.tv_usec );

    //printf("Time started = %ld\n; Time ended = %ld\n: Time taken = %ld\n",
    //       initial.it_value.tv_usec, updated.it_value.tv_usec,
    //       initial.it_value.tv_usec - updated.it_value.tv_usec);
    return 0;
}

// accuracy is +/-1 microsecond, not millisecond
```

The resulting output, even with nothing being done between the two calls to `setitimer()` is:

```
Time value: 1.999999
Time interval: 1.999999
end interval counter: 1.999999
end value counter: 2.3999
```

Comment: I am a bit surprised that the counters counted `up` rather than `down`

Answer (score 0):

`setitimer` and `getitimer` are not the right functions to use for profiling. They relate to *interval timers* which are timers that generate an alarm (signal more accurately) when the timer expires.

The main options for achieving what you want are the [`clock`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) or [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) APIs.

Comment: Additionally, POSIX marks both [`getitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html)
and [`setitimer()`] as obsolescent, and you should aim to use the [`timer_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_gettime.html) and [`timer_settime()`] functions instead.  These have nanosecond resolution (they use `struct timespec` instead of `struct timeval`).

Comment: Do these functions allow for virtual timing? I am interested in finding the time taken to execute the instruction  for (unsigned int i; i < UINT_MAX; i++) 
  sum += 1./i;